# How to make tkinter postpone canvas updates?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

Using my testing, I found that after every shape you draw on the canvas, it recalculates and draws the pixels.

```
c = Canvas(root)
c.pack()

c.create_line(10, 10, 50, 50)
# Draws line on canvas immediately.

c.create_line(20, 20, 60, 60)
# Draws second line on canvas.
```

This seems highly inefficient as I'm trying to create dozens of shapes per frame (as in each simulation update). It would probably be better to wait until I've queued up all my draw commands, then tell the canvas to redraw the frame all in one go.

So far I tried creating a canvas using the interactive shell without calling `mainloop` or even `update` on the root, but after each draw function it redrew the canvas!

Something like this would be ideal:

```
c = Canvas(root)
c.pack()

c.queue_create_line(10, 10, 50, 50)
# Don't draw line yet.

c.queue_create_line(20, 20, 60, 60)
# Also don't draw yet.

c.draw_queue()
# Finally draw both lines at once.
```

Please let me know if there is a way to fix this problem.

Comment: `tk.Canvas` does not work the way you think: it is not a `pygame` surface, or some other GUI toolkit canvas. Its items are drawn, moved, modified individually; there is no real notion of a frame or FPS. The canvas maintains a dirty bounding box, and redraws only the portions that were altered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Using my testing, I found that after every shape you draw on the canvas, it recalculates and draws the pixels.

The behavior you see is only because you are running from a python shell. In normal operation, the canvas will not update the display immediately. The only time the display is updated is when you call `update()` or your function exits and control is given back to the event loop. Because you are running from the pythons shell, the display is updated after processing each command.